# Duda al Convertir date time a fecha Unix y ISO +1 o +2

Tags: javascript

Tengo un proceso que recupera de una API esta fecha en este formato: 06/11/2019 19:14:00. Necesito convertir este valor al ISO y además a Unix.

Anteriormente he trabajado de la siguiente forma:
convierto time a unix y posteriormente a ISO, el problema que veo es el resultado, me da dos horas menos al ser UTC ¿no tendría que ser una hora menos ya que estamos en horario de invierno? Otra api que tengo si me da el Unix en +1 o +2 dependiendo del horario.

```
time = '06/11/2019 19:14:00';
Unix: time2 = new Date(time).getTime() / 1000;
ISO: var date = new Date(time2 * 1000).toISOString();
```

EDIT

Acabo de encontrar un problema me esta ordenando la fecha mal

> "recvTime" : "2019-06-11T18:14:00.000Z"

tendria que ser

> 2019-11-06T18:14:00.000Z

, esta poniendo el mes donde el dia.

da este error `RangeError: Invalid time value<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Date.toISOString`

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente lo he solucionado de tal forma:

```
Unix: var time2 = moment(time, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss") / 1000;
ISO: var recvTime = new Date(time3 * 1000).toISOString();
```

Un saludo, espero que sea de ayuda.